# Deserializing a string with escape characters using JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a string like this:

```
"[
  {
    \"SomeProperty\": 22
  }
 ]"
```

I'm trying to deserialize it into a list of known types:

```
        string toProcess = $@"[{text}]".Replace("\n", ",");
        toProcess = Regex.Unescape(toProcess);
        List<KnownType> objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KnownType>>(toProcess);
```

However I see that it's attempting to deserialize a string containing the `\"` characters, and it's failing with `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object`.  How do I properly deserialize this?

Comment: Your string is not a valid JSON. So you can't deserialize it. You could verify this using this https://jsonlint.com/. Furthermore a valid JSON string doesn't need any manipulation before you deserialize it. Hence I think that your approach is not correct.

Comment: Are you sure your json is exactly like this, or is it what you see in debugger window?

Comment: @Christos the string I'm working with is not valid JSON.  I'm trying to make it valid JSON.

Comment: @L.B - yes - this is the string.  It's intended for display somewhere else but I need to deserialize it so I have to correct it into json.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `string toProcess = $@"[{text}]".Replace("\n", ",");`

```
string text = @"[
  {
    \""SomeProperty\"": 22
  }
 ]";


text = Regex.Unescape(text);
var objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KnownType>>(text);

Console.WriteLine(objectList[0].SomeProperty);//22
```

This code works as expected.

Comment: I don't have a valid JSON string - I have an abomination that I'm correcting, including `\"`. not `\""`.  I also have inline `\n` instead of commas - so the first line appears to be required.

Comment: @SB2055 \"" translates into a literaly string of \", so I'm not sure what you mean.